# npm config list in "sub-package" of a workspace results in ENOWORKSPACES

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-devops

I have the following project structure:

```
workspace_test
│   package.json
│
└───dist
    └───libs
        └───pkg
                package.json
```

The `workspace_test/project.json` contains **npm workspaces**:

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "workspaces": [
    "dist/libs/*"
  ]
}
```

The `dist/libs/pkg/package.json`, is the output of a compilation, and does not contain anything significant (I just initialized it with `npm init -y` for testing purposes).

If I run `npm config list` in the root of the project, I successfully get output from it. But if I run it inside `dist/libs/pkg`, I get the following erroneous output:

```
npm ERR! code ENOWORKSPACES
npm ERR! This command does not support workspaces.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Elias\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-05T07_00_50_459Z-debug-0.log
```

The debug log doesn't seem to provide any more relevant details.

How would I go about fixing this?

## Reproduction:

Run the following commands to reproduce the issue:

```
mkdir workspace_test
cd workspace_test
mkdir dist/libs/pkg
cd dist/libs/pkg
npm init -y
```

Add `"workspaces": ["dist/libs/*"]` to `workspace_test/project.json`. Assure the shell in still in `dist/libs/pkg`, and then the problem should occur by running:

```
npm config list
```

## Versions:

*Should* be the latest stable, as I've tried to upgrade them to fix the problem at hand.

```
node : v18.16.1
npm  : 9.7.2
```

## Additional background information (Azure Pipelines):

This whole ordeal is happening in an azure publish pipeline. So **it**, being the azure provided Npm@1 task, tries to run `npm config list` in a package artifact. I've found that running `npm config list --no-workspaces` works, but I don't think I have control over the arguments.

The task looks like this:

```yaml
- ${{ each package in parameters.packages }}:
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Publish ${{ package.packageName }} Package'
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        command: publish
        workingDir: ${{ package.pathToDist }}
        publishRegistry: useFeed
        publishFeed: ${{ parameters.npmFeedId }}
```